# How do I define a conditional class selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a table row editable when 'Edit' button is clicked.The method I have tried is working but it is selecting not just the current row but entire row of the table. Is there any way I can put a condition on selector to make editable only the current row?

**HTML**

```
{% for i in data %}
<tr>
<td class="cell">{{i['roll_no']}}</td>
<td class="cell">{{i['name']}}</td>
<td class="cell">{{i['username']}}</td>
<td class="cell">{{i['password']}}</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-new" id="edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-new" id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() === 'Edit') {
        $(this).html('Save');
        $('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'True');
        $('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': 'pink','color': 'black'});
    } else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        $(".cell").each(function() {
            var str = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(str);
        });
        $('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'False');
        $('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': '#032F55','color': 'white'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a CSS class then [Class Selector `(".class")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used to target the element and attach event handlers.

*HTML*

```
 <a class="btn btn-new edit" id="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
```

In the event handler, use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse upto parent `TR` element then you can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `.cell` elements

*Script*

```
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    var cells = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell');
    if ($(this).html() === 'Edit') {
        $(this).html('Save');
        .attr('contenteditable', 'True');
        cells.css({
            'backgroundColor': 'pink',
            'color': 'black'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        cells.each(function () {
            var str = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(str);
        });
        cells.attr('contenteditable', 'False');
        cells.css({
            'backgroundColor': '#032F55',
            'color': 'white'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. I think I don't need to put **id** attribute there.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari, Yes you should remove the `id` attribute

Comment: I accepted your answer only because of your line ` var cells = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell') ` . It's better to communicate the DOM less. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using class name .cell so it is selecting all rows having class .cell. So try something like

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell') instead of ('.cell').
```

This will find the current row in which edit is there

Code will be like:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() === 'Edit') {
        $(this).html('Save');
        $ $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'True');
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': 'pink','color': 'black'});
    } else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        $(".cell").each(function() {
            var str = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(str);
        });
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'False');
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': '#032F55','color': 'white'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the parent tr then find the element with class cell

```
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() === 'Edit') {
        $(this).html('Save');
        $('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'True');
        $('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': 'pink','color': 'black'});
    } else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        $(".cell").each(function() {
            var str = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(str);
        });
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').attr('contenteditable', 'False');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell').css({'backgroundColor': '#032F55','color': 'white'});
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it would be better to declare a variable to hold the selected element than accessing the DOM multiple times.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari yes you are correct i just copied your code in OP and change a bit

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

- You are looping the `data` array to create the rows so it is a bad practice to set common id `edit` for `Edit` link. You can use the index of the loop to make unique id of the `Edit` anchor.
- You need to only select the `td` that are on the same rows of the `Edit` link which you can do by getting the corresponding row where there is the `Edit` link which you clicked and then finding the `td` will class `.cell`.
- For elements that are generated dynamically it is always a good practice to use the JQuery class selector instead of id selector.

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() === 'Edit') {
        $(this).html('Save');
        var cellElements = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell');
        cellElements.attr('contenteditable', 'True');
        cellElements.css({'backgroundColor': 'pink','color': 'black'});
    } else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        var cellElements = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell');
        cellElements.each(function() {
            var str = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(str);
        });
        cellElements.attr('contenteditable', 'False');
        cellElements.css({'backgroundColor': '#032F55','color': 'white'});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Roll No 1</td>
      <td class="cell">Name 1</td>
      <td class="cell">username 1</td>
      <td class="cell">password 1</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-new edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-new" id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="cell">Roll No 2</td>
      <td class="cell">Name 2</td>
      <td class="cell">username 2</td>
      <td class="cell">password 2</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-new edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-new" id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```